# creating new variables based on other variables/aggregate data in r

Tags: r

I apologize for the poor title. I'm drawing a blank and cannot figure out the best way to handle this issue...

Here's my data:

```
dat <- data.frame(v1 = c(rep(1:3, 2),4),
              v2 = c(5,5,999,10,999,10, 10))
```

The dataset that I'm using has a variable (V1) as an ID. Each time the ID completes a task the system spits out a new row. It puts a '5' in V2 when the first task is complete, it puts a '10' when the second task is complete and it puts a '999' when the third task is complete. I'd like to change it to look like this:

```
V1 s1 s2 s3
1  1  1  0
2  1  0  1
3  0  1  1
4  0  1  0
```

I feel like it should be rather easy, but I can't think of any simple way to do it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use `table`?

```
table(dat)

   v2
v1  5 10 999
  1 1  1   0
  2 1  0   1
  3 0  1   1
  4 0  1   0
```

Comment: Right. Obviously. Wow, thanks a lot... not sure why I didn't think of that before. I was just thinking about it wrong. Thanks again.